# Visual Studio 2012 shows all templates twice

Tags: templates, visual-studio-2012

I just installed VS12 Ultimate, and when creating a new project, this showed up:
[image: screenshot]

Is this a known bug? All templates seem to be exactly the same and it doesn't really affect coding, but still, it looks like crap. Everything else seems to function just fine.

Comment: From what I have seen, I think VS 12 has some issues...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the answer to this question is, in fact, quite simple!

VS12 was showing double templates because of remains of an older installation. In order to fix this, I simply uninstalled VS12 again and removed visual studio folders in the My Documents folders, as well as any other folders that held visual studio files.

After this, I installed VS12 again and all was well.